# adb install to android emulator shows success but app not found

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

im trying to find an emulator that can run an apk

I renamed the apk to .zip and saw armeabi-v7a in the lib folder so i chose the below emulator image as it was stated that android 9.0/11.0 works with armeabi-v7a apks
[image]

Then i used adb install to install the said apk. The result shows success and the package is there but the app isnt. Is there a reason for this?
This is the log from "adb logcat"

```
03-25 14:56:24.885  1115  1115 I         : free_cache(272636739) avail 14570733568
03-25 14:56:44.743  1296  1326 D NativeLibraryHelper: call FindSupportedAbi, param: supportedAbisArray=x86 armeabi-v7a armeabi
03-25 14:56:45.018  1296  1326 D NativeLibraryHelper: native FindSupportedAbi return! ret=1 abi=armeabi-v7a
03-25 14:56:47.735  2981  2994 D NativeLibraryHelper: call FindSupportedAbi, param: supportedAbisArray=x86 armeabi-v7a armeabi
03-25 14:56:47.825  1296  1325 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.INTERNET in package: com.tencent.wework at: Binary XML file line #59
03-25 14:56:47.826  1296  1325 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE in package: com.tencent.wework at: Binary XML file line #60
03-25 14:56:47.826  1296  1325 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE in package: com.tencent.wework at: Binary XML file line #61
03-25 14:56:47.826  1296  1325 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.WAKE_LOCK in package: com.tencent.wework at: Binary XML file line #62
03-25 14:56:47.826  1296  1325 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.VIBRATE in package: com.tencent.wework at: Binary XML file line #64
03-25 14:56:47.826  1296  1325 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED in package: com.tencent.wework at: Binary XML file line #66
03-25 14:56:47.826  1296  1325 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in package: com.tencent.wework at: Binary XML file line #67
03-25 14:56:47.826  1296  1325 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY in package: com.tencent.wework at: Binary XML file line #68
03-25 14:56:47.826  1296  1325 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.BLUETOOTH in package: com.tencent.wework at: Binary XML file line #69
03-25 14:56:47.826  1296  1325 W PackageParser: Unknown element under <manifest>: meta-data at /data/app/vmdl1415924628.tmp/base.apk Binary XML file line #143
03-25 14:56:47.895  1296  1325 D NativeLibraryHelper: call FindSupportedAbi, param: supportedAbisArray=x86 armeabi-v7a armeabi
03-25 14:56:48.606  1296  1325 I PackageManager: do copyNativeBinariesForSupportedAbi copyRet=1
03-25 14:56:48.608  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Package com.tencent.wework desires unavailable shared library android.test.base; ignoring!
03-25 14:56:48.608  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Package com.tencent.wework desires unavailable shared library com.here.android; ignoring!
03-25 14:56:48.624  1296  1310 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.tencent.wework appid=10037 user=-1: installPackageLI
03-25 14:56:48.680  1296  1325 I PackageManager: Package com.tencent.wework codePath changed from /data/app/com.tencent.wework-2 to /data/app/com.tencent.wework-1; Retaining data and using new
03-25 14:56:48.680  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Package com.tencent.wework desires unavailable shared library android.test.base; ignoring!
03-25 14:56:48.680  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Package com.tencent.wework desires unavailable shared library com.here.android; ignoring!
03-25 14:56:48.683  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Code path for com.tencent.wework changing from /data/app/com.tencent.wework-2 to /data/app/com.tencent.wework-1
03-25 14:56:48.683  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Resource path for com.tencent.wework changing from /data/app/com.tencent.wework-2 to /data/app/com.tencent.wework-1
03-25 14:56:48.683  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Skipping provider name com.tencent.wework.fileprovider (in package com.tencent.wework): name already used by com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.687  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Non-privileged app; cap priority to 0; package: com.tencent.wework activity: com.tencent.wework.apihost.WWAPIActivity origPrio: 2147483647
03-25 14:56:48.704  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.704  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.704  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.704  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.huawei.permission.sec.SDK_LAUNCHER in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.704  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.huawei.pushagent.permission.RICHMEDIA_PROVIDER in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission android.permission.ALARM_LOCK in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission android.permission.RECEIVE_USER_PRESENT in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.huawei.systemmanager.permission.ACCESS_INTERFACE in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.coloros.mcs.permission.RECIEVE_MCS_MESSAGE in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.asus.msa.SupplementaryDID.ACCESS in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Not granting permission android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES to package com.tencent.wework (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x38583e44)
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Not granting permission android.permission.RECOVERY to package com.tencent.wework (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x38583e44)
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Not granting permission android.permission.REBOOT to package com.tencent.wework (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x38583e44)
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.tencent.wecastlauncher.READ in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission android.hardware.usb.host in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission android.hardware.usb.accessory in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.705  1296  1325 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.huawei.appmarket.service.commondata.permission.GET_COMMON_DATA in package com.tencent.wework
03-25 14:56:48.733  1296  1325 I art     : Starting a blocking GC Explicit
03-25 14:56:48.753  1296  1325 I art     : Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 15735(956KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(80KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 8MB/13MB, paused 313us total 19.779ms
03-25 14:56:48.802  1115  1115 E         : Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl1415924628.tmp: No such file or directory
03-25 14:56:48.817  1296  1325 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.tencent.wework appid=10037 user=0: pkg removed
03-25 14:56:48.852  1695  1695 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1358 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:613 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:613 com.android.coreservice.CoreBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:85 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:3073
03-25 14:56:48.859  1821  1821 I appstore: app Not Started
03-25 14:56:48.869  1725  1725 D LdHotSeatAdImp: Test: updateAHotSetIcon viewItem=null
03-25 14:56:48.871  1296  1342 I InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
03-25 14:56:48.892  1296  1342 I InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
03-25 14:56:48.895  1296  1342 I InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
03-25 14:56:48.901  1710  1710 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1358 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:613 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:613 com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:3073
03-25 14:56:48.906  1725  1725 W Launcher: setApplicationContext called twice! old=com.android.launcher3.LauncherApplication@7de01d2 new=com.android.launcher3.LauncherApplication@7de01d2
03-25 14:56:48.927  1695  1695 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1358 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:613 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:613 com.android.coreservice.CoreBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:77 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:3073
03-25 14:56:48.933  1562  1562 E PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
03-25 14:56:48.933  1562  1562 D CarrierSvcBindHelper: No carrier app for: 0
03-25 14:56:48.934  1562  1562 E PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
03-25 14:56:48.934  1562  1562 D CarrierSvcBindHelper: No carrier app for: 0
03-25 14:56:48.934  1562  1562 D CarrierConfigLoader: mHandler: 9 phoneId: 0
03-25 14:56:48.993  1296  1309 W Searchables: No global search activity found
03-25 14:56:48.994  1296  1309 W Searchables: No global search activity found
03-25 14:56:49.016  1296  1309 W VoiceInteractionManagerService: no available voice recognition services found for user 0
03-25 14:56:49.065  3566  3566 D su      : su invoked.
03-25 14:56:49.069  3567  3567 D su      : starting daemon client 10019 10019
03-25 14:56:49.075  3568  3568 D su      : connecting client 3565
03-25 14:56:49.079  3571  3571 D su      : remote pid: 3565
03-25 14:56:49.084  3572  3572 D su      : remote pts_slave:
03-25 14:56:49.088  3573  3573 D su      : remote uid: 10019
03-25 14:56:49.093  3574  3574 D su      : remote req pid: 1821
03-25 14:56:49.098  3575  3575 D su      : remote args: 1
03-25 14:56:49.102  3579  3579 D su      : su invoked.
03-25 14:56:49.102  3577  3577 D su      : waiting for child exit
03-25 14:56:49.111  3580  3580 D su      : db allowed
03-25 14:56:49.117  3582  3582 D su      : 10019 /system/bin/app_process32 executing 0 /system/bin/sh using binary /system/bin/sh : sh
03-25 14:56:49.137  3585  3585 D su      : sending code
03-25 14:56:49.142  3587  3587 D su      : client exited 255
03-25 14:56:49.144  3586  3586 D su      : child exited
03-25 14:56:49.181  3591  3591 D su      : su invoked.
03-25 14:56:49.184  1725  1725 W Launcher: setApplicationContext called twice! old=com.android.launcher3.LauncherApplication@7de01d2 new=com.android.launcher3.LauncherApplication@7de01d2
03-25 14:56:49.186  3595  3595 D su      : starting daemon client 10019 10019
03-25 14:56:49.191  3597  3597 D su      : connecting client 3590
03-25 14:56:49.195  3600  3600 D su      : remote pid: 3590
03-25 14:56:49.198  3601  3601 D su      : remote pts_slave:
03-25 14:56:49.202  3602  3602 D su      : remote uid: 10019
03-25 14:56:49.206  3603  3603 D su      : remote req pid: 1821
03-25 14:56:49.210  3604  3604 D su      : remote args: 1
03-25 14:56:49.214  3606  3606 D su      : waiting for child exit
03-25 14:56:49.214  3608  3608 D su      : su invoked.
03-25 14:56:49.219  3609  3609 D su      : db allowed
03-25 14:56:49.222  3611  3611 D su      : 10019 /system/bin/app_process32 executing 0 /system/bin/sh using binary /system/bin/sh : sh
03-25 14:56:49.261  1725  1725 I Launcher: Deferring update until onResume
03-25 14:56:49.267  1296  1558 W BackupManagerService: dataChanged but no participant pkg='com.android.launcher3' uid=10029
03-25 14:56:49.268  1725  1725 I Launcher: Deferring update until onResume
03-25 14:56:49.290  1725  1725 I Launcher: Deferring update until onResume
03-25 14:56:49.291  3617  3617 D su      : sending code
03-25 14:56:49.297  3621  3621 D su      : client exited 0
03-25 14:56:49.304  3619  3619 D su      : child exited
03-25 14:56:49.394  3581  3581 I appproc : exec app_process! cmdline: /system/bin com.android.commands.am.Am broadcast -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.cyanogenmod.superuser.SuReceiver --ei binary_version 16 --es from_name u0_a19 --es desired_name  --ei uid 10019 --ei desired_uid 0 --es command /system/bin/sh --es action allow --user 0
03-25 14:56:49.394  3581  3581 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
03-25 14:56:49.400  3581  3581 D AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF
03-25 14:56:49.416  3610  3610 I appproc : exec app_process! cmdline: /system/bin com.android.commands.am.Am broadcast -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.cyanogenmod.superuser.SuReceiver --ei binary_version 16 --es from_name u0_a19 --es desired_name  --ei uid 10019 --ei desired_uid 0 --es command /system/bin/sh --es action allow --user 0
03-25 14:56:49.416  3610  3610 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
03-25 14:56:49.418  3610  3610 D AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF
03-25 14:56:49.460  3581  3581 D ICU     : No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
03-25 14:56:49.460  3610  3610 D ICU     : No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
03-25 14:56:49.531  3581  3581 W art     : Failed to stat, will retry: /data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@am.jar@classes.dex.flock: No such file or directory
03-25 14:56:49.532  3610  3610 D libnativebridge: PreInitializeNativeBridge name=unknown instruction_set=x86
03-25 14:56:49.533  3610  3610 D libnativebridge: call UnloadNativeBridge! state=1
03-25 14:56:49.533  3581  3581 D libnativebridge: PreInitializeNativeBridge name=unknown instruction_set=x86
03-25 14:56:49.534  3581  3581 D libnativebridge: call UnloadNativeBridge! state=1
03-25 14:56:49.568  3581  3581 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
03-25 14:56:49.568  3610  3610 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
03-25 14:56:49.568  3581  3581 E android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-25 14:56:49.568  3610  3610 E android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-25 14:56:49.569  3610  3610 I Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
03-25 14:56:49.569  3581  3581 I Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
03-25 14:56:49.613  3581  3581 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
03-25 14:56:49.613  3610  3610 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
03-25 14:56:49.648  3610  3610 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-25 14:56:49.648  3581  3581 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-25 14:56:49.750  1821  1821 D EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class java.lang.Integer
03-25 14:56:49.750  1821  1821 D EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.h
03-25 14:56:49.904  1821  1821 D EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class java.lang.Integer
03-25 14:56:49.904  1821  1821 D EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.h
```

Comment: An app can have one, two, three, ... or no app icon. That depends on the app. There are also apps designed for Android-TV devices, these apps define the app icon(s) in a different way.

Comment: Cross-posted to Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246043/44325